# check if user has sent the mail successfully

Tags: swift, macos, email, cocoa

I working with swift 4 for macOS.
I know that I can get the "success result" of a print operation and can check if the user has sent the print job or canceled it with this code:

```
let printOp = NSPrintOperation()
printOp.runModal(for: view.window!, delegate: self, didRun: #selector(self.printOperationDidRun(_:success:contextInfo:)), contextInfo: nil)

@objc func printOperationDidRun(_ printOperation: NSPrintOperation, success: Bool, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   // DO SOMETHHING
}
```

Is there an way to check this with e-mail?
For Example my user can send a Mail, if he press a button:

```
let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingService.Name.composeEmail)!
let items:[Any] = ["My Content"]
service.perform(withItems: items)
```

The mail app will open but I don't know, what the user will done.
Was the mail sent? Canceled?

Is there a way to check this?

Comment: check for the delegate methods for mail

Comment: yes, but I guess there is no method which gives me the result, that the mail was sent: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssharingservicedelegate